# Not correct timezone php server returned

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timezone

I have a Laravel+nginx server in the docker. Database MariaDB separately on this server and here I set Moscow timezone (it's correct timezone to me)
But then I return data from server, I had it in UTC +0.

database config

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'timezone' => '+3:00',
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

app config

```
'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'Europe/Moscow'),
```

In the MariaDB server I set the Moscow timezone and data saved.

php.ini

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
max_execution_time = 1000
max_input_time = 1000
memory_limit=4G
date.timezone = "Europe/Moscow"
```

Comment: In general, you'll have a much happier time running/storing everything in UTC, and converting on the front-end to the user's timezone.

Comment: You should set timezone `default_time_zone = 'Europe/Moscow'` in mariadb under `[mariadb]` section too if you access from server

Comment: [mariadb] section which one? I dont understand in which file or config?

Comment: The database server itself has its own config. You can add the default timezone in there. What you declare as database config is inside some PHP code, but not the DB server itself.

Comment: Definitely agree with @ceejayoz here, you should almost always be using UTC for backend.

Comment: What does the data look like in the database? How are you storing it? How are you retrieving it? Too many variables here.